# css :hover effect cover a greater height than the text in bootstrap nav bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

[image]

Currently i am having this problem where i increased the padding on the bootstrap nav bar to make it bigger.  I made the text bigger.  My concern is that when i use the hover effect, it only covers the text and not the bigger area.  Is there a way to sort of add padding on the hover effect? What is the best way i should approach this?

This is my html

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">konek</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
                            <li class="active"><a href="{{ url_for('timeline') }}">Timeline</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url_for('profile') }}">My Profile</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url_for('update_account') }}">Update Account</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a></li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
                            <li class=""><a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Log In</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the :hover styles to the parent of the text, which should fill the Navbar.

The parent in this case should be the `li` tag. In Bootstrap, iirc, it should fill the Navbar by default.

Comment: You should add the :hover styles to the li tag, which should fill the Navbar by default (Navbar should be flexbox) in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

Is the :hover css style applied to just  tag element or the li. If the :hover styling is on the  tag then change it be on the li like `li:hover`, if the hover effect is on the li then make sure the navbar is 100% of the parent and that the ul is also 100%. That way the hover will take the full height of the navbar rather than just the text.

```
ul {
   height: 100%;
}

li {
   height: 100%;
}

li:hover {
   ...hover-code
}
```